# Create ISO image file from my CD/DVD optical disc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, optical-media, iso, ripping

I am looking for a software that reads CD/DVDs and stores the content to an ISO file.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If you accept running from within Wine, try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)

Comment: Did you try searching your Software Center? All the DVD ripping tools there can do that. Do you have any further requirements?

Answer (score 2):

**[K9Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy)** can do that at least for DVDs:

[image: K9Copy]
<sup>*K9Copy* (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy); click image for larger variant)</sup>

It's main goal is to make DVD9 content fit onto a DVD5 (by e.g. re-encoding video, or drop unwanted audio tracks). The result is then saved to an `.iso` file. So if you don't "shrink" anything, you should get a 1:1 copy in the resulting ISO.

Though development stopped in 2011, there's a fork which is continued until today: *K9Copy Reloaded*. You can find packages for Debian and Ubuntu [here to download](http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html). As the name and [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy) make it sound like it requires a full KDE environment, the [list of requirements on the project page](http://k9copy-reloaded.sourceforge.net/#Prerequisites) seem to confirm this for the fork as well, and list a.o. "Choice of Qt4 and Kde4 OR Qt5 and KF5".

Alternatives I can think of: the easiest would be using a simple command line IMHO. If you know where your DVD sits (in my example, I assume `/dev/dvd` – to find out the real one, see [How can find out the device Id of my unmounted DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/26571/68291)):

```
dd if=/dev/dvd of=mydvd.iso
# or
mkisofs -r -o file.iso /dev/dvd
```

should do – for any "ISO disk" (i.e. DVD and Video-CD alike). No specific requirements for this, as `dd` usually is already pre-installed on most *nix systems.

Also see:

- [Linux/Ubuntu native (not Wine) alternative to DVD-Shrink, that can compress a DVD image to a smaller size to fit on a writeable DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/537184/68291)
- [Is there an alternative to DVD-Shrink, that can compress a DVD image to a smaller size to fit on a writeable DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/129891/68291)
- [Ripping DVD to iso - Accurately](https://askubuntu.com/q/147800/68291) (also recommends `dd` – but also mentions `ddrescue` and `gddrescue` in case there might be "read errors")

Comment: `dd` only is good when there is no error in reading the device. But about CD/DVD there is usually some read errors that stops `dd` commands.

Comment: For that case, see e.g. [Ripping DVD to iso - Accurately](http://askubuntu.com/q/147800/68291) (just found that after I wrote my answer). The highest ranking answer exactly recommends that, and the comments give some fix-ups for the problem you've mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a command line tool, ddrescue, for this. I don't know how well it would work if the disc has any form of DRM but it worked fine for my old home videos that were burned to a DVD.

`sudo apt-get install gddrescue`

Then use this command to create an iso in the directory of your choice:

`ddrescue /dev/sr0 ~/isos/filename.iso`

Where /dev/sr0 is the path to your optical drive.